# object evolutions is not a member of package play.api.db.slick

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm a newbie to Play framework and can't figure out why I'm getting this error in my application loader class that I copied and pasted from the Play 2.6 documention [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Evolutions) with some modifications for new versions of slick and slick-evolutions.

Here is the part of my build.sbt that references the libraries:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.2"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(evolutions, jdbc)
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(jdbc,  ehcache , ws , specs2 % Test , guice )
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("com.typesafe.play" %% "play" % "2.6.11")
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "3.0.1"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "3.0.1"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.36")
```

Here is my application.conf

```
play.application.loader=AppComponents
```

And here is the AppComponents class which I put in my root directory

```
import play.api.ApplicationLoader.Context
import play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext
import play.api.db.{Database, DBComponents, HikariCPComponents}
import play.api.db.slick.evolutions.{SlickEvolutionsComponents}
import play.api.routing.Router
import play.filters.HttpFiltersComponents

class AppComponents(cntx: Context)
  extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(cntx)
    with DBComponents
    with SlickEvolutionsComponents
    with HikariCPComponents
    with HttpFiltersComponents
{
  // this will actually run the database migrations on startup
  applicationEvolutions
}
```

I've examined the play-slick-evolutions_2.12-3.0.1.jar jar that was downloaded and it indeed has has play.api.db.slick.evolutions there.  I've also tried earlier versions that comport exactly with the code in the Play 2.6 documentation, but there too, evolutions is not a member of the package.

Answer (score 0):

First, a project rebuild took care of the initial error, but it did not solve the problem with the Application Loader.  To fix this I returned to the Play 2.6 documentation and restored the class to the segment they provided and removed the play-slick sbt entries, restoring to the entries in the documentation.  There was still a problem, and on finding another example it became evident that I didn't have a complete class.  Here it is:

```
import play.api.ApplicationLoader
import play.api.ApplicationLoader.Context
import play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext
import play.api.db.{Database, DBComponents, HikariCPComponents}
import play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsComponents
import play.api.routing.Router
import play.filters.HttpFiltersComponents

class MyApplicationLoader extends ApplicationLoader {
  def load(context: Context) = {
    new MyComponents(context).application
  }
}

class MyComponents(cntx: Context)
  extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(cntx)
    with DBComponents
    with EvolutionsComponents
    with HikariCPComponents
    with HttpFiltersComponents
{
  // this will actually run the database migrations on startup
  lazy val router = Router.empty
  applicationEvolutions
}
```

I also adjusted my application.conf setting to:

```
play.application.loader=MyApplicationLoader
```

Note that I still need to add the routing because the lazy val router = Route.empty gives a web page that says:

Action Not Found
For request 'GET /'

These routes have been tried, in this order: